# Cannot find symbol method setOnClickListener error in Android

Tags: android

I am getting the following error:

> "Error:(35, 16) error: cannot find symbol method setOnClickListner()"

When I run my android program from android studio.

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.optechsoft.pos;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView totalTextView;
    EditText percentageTxt;
    EditText numberTxt;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        totalTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.totalTextview);
        percentageTxt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.percentageTxt);
        numberTxt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.numberTxt);

        Button calcBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.calcBtn);
        calcBtn.setOnClickListner(new View.OnClickListener(){
           @Override
            public void onClick (View view) {
                float percentage = Float.parseFloat(percentageTxt.getText().toString());
                float dec = percentage / 100;
                float total = dec * Float.parseFloat(numberTxt.getText().toString());
                totalTextView.setText(Float.toString(total));
           }

        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: clean the project and rebuild

Comment: check spelling.. Its setOnClickListener

Comment: replace the code which i have posted as answer.

Comment: You are using android studio na,please do use shortcut keys,so you can avoid such mistakes,for example you can use as ctrl+space?

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
setOnClickListner
```

to

```
setOnClickListener
```

Correct your spelling

Answer (score 1):

Change `setOnClickListner` to `setOnClickListener`

```
Button calcBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.calcBtn);
calcBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
     @Override
     public void onClick (View view) {
          float percentage = Float.parseFloat(percentageTxt.getText().toString());
          float dec = percentage / 100;
          float total = dec * Float.parseFloat(numberTxt.getText().toString());
          totalTextView.setText(Float.toString(total));
     }

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace your code as,

```
        calcBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            float percentage = Float.parseFloat(percentageTxt.getText().toString());
            float dec = percentage / 100;
            float total = dec * Float.parseFloat(numberTxt.getText().toString());
            totalTextView.setText(Float.toString(total));   
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You misspelled：

```
setOnClickListner
```

It should be:

```
setOnClickListener
```

Comment: Not necessary to add the same answer what they mentioned